# Python exe giving error in connecting to Teradata, however works fine while running from spyder

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, exe, teradata, pyinstaller

My python program works fine while running from Spyder.
When i convert that into an exe file using pyinstaller and run it, I get the following error

sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata

I figured out that below line of code is creating problem in the exe while working fine in spyder as a .py file.

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('teradata://user_id:password/dbname?driver= Teradata')

This plugin is available with Spyder. Is it possible that it is not available in pyinstaller? Does any one encountered this issue before?

Comment: pyinstaller failed to detect that you need sqlalchemy-teradata. I guess it's because sqlalchemy loads dialect modules dynamically. I'm not too familiar with pyinstaller, maybe you can force it to include sqlalchemy-teradata?

Comment: i tried sqlalchemy-teradata as well. But no luck